# Convert int16 to byte array

Tags: c++, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm really new to C, and so a bit confused.

I am trying to convert an int16 to a byte[] array.

I have a int16 like -200, and I want to convert it into a byte[2] array, like the following example does.

```
Velocity = -200 = hex FF38 = [hex FF] [hex 38] = [255] [56]
```

I am taking the values and passing them to the serial port like below, but I need to pass the int16, and have a function convert it to the byte[] for me.

```
Serial.print(255,BYTE);
Serial.print(56,BYTE);
```

I found the following code, but couldn't get it to work

```
Serial.print((velocity & 0xff00) >> 8, BYTE);
Serial.print(velocity & 0xff, BYTE);
```

Any suggestions?? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What didn't work in your last example ?

Comment: What do you mean you "couldn't get it to work"? Have you tried using printf or anything to see what the result of `(velocity & 0xFF00)>>8` is?

Comment: `Serial.print` ... hmmm ... are you sure your code is C, and your compiler is for C? Is `print` a function pointer part of an object of a struct type? Anyway ... Why does it not work? What is the compiler message? What happens or doesn't happen? *help us help you* and make sure about the language

Comment: @pmg Good point, looks like C++ to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach looks fine, but maybe you're getting tripped up by an [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue?

> Serial protocols may also be regarded as either little or big-endian at the bit- and/or byte-levels (which may differ). Many serial interfaces, such as the ubiquitous USB, are little-endian at the bit-level. Physical standards like RS-232, RS-422 and RS-485 are also typically used with UARTs that send the least significant bit first...

Your code sends the most significant byte first ("big-endian").